# How do I prevent the main page from scrolling when returning from the page I just opened in Flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, scroll, mobile-development

**When I click on a link to open a new page, it functions as expected. However, when I attempt to return to the main page by scrolling through the newly opened page, it starts scrolling upwards along with the main page. How can I prevent this behavior from happening?**

This video shows the issue
https://youtube.com/shorts/7Q1NESukzmw?feature=share

***Code below is for my home/main page.***

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:nasa_flutter/route_names.dart';
import 'widgets/menu_cards.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  final ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _scrollController.dispose();
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black87,
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.indigo.shade900,
        title: const Text("--------"),
      ),
     
      body: SafeArea(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          controller: _scrollController,
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              MenuCards(
                text: ".......",
                imagePath: ".......",
                onButtonPressed: () {
                  Navigator.pushNamed(context, RouteNames.somewhere);
                },
              ),
              MenuCards(
                  text: ".....",
                  imagePath: "....",
                  onButtonPressed: () {
                    Navigator.pushNamed(context, RouteNames.somewhereelse);
                  }),
              //...... Other Menu Card. In total there are 11 cards.
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Code below is for my newPage.

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:loading_animation_widget/loading_animation_widget.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';
import 'widgets/news_container.dart';

class NewsPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const NewsPage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const NewsScreen();
  }
}

class NewsScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const NewsScreen({super.key});


  @override
  State<NewsScreen> createState() => _NewsScreenState();
}

class _NewsScreenState extends State<NewsScreen> {
  late Future<List<News>> newsFuture;

  @override
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    newsFuture = _fetchNews();
  }

  Future<void> _launchInWebViewOrVC(Uri url) async {
    if (!await launchUrl(
      url,
      mode: LaunchMode.inAppWebView,
      webViewConfiguration: const WebViewConfiguration(
          headers: <String, String>{'my_header_key': 'my_header_value'}),
    )) {
      throw Exception('Could not launch $url');
    }
  }

  Future<List<News>> _fetchNews() async {
    final url = Uri.parse('https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines');
    final queryParameters = {
      'q': "....",
      'apiKey': '....',
      'language': "...",
      'category': '...',
      'sortBy': '...',
    };
    final response =
    await http.get(url.replace(queryParameters: queryParameters));

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final data = jsonDecode(response.body);
      List<News> objects = [];
      for (var news in data['.....']) {
        objects.add(News.fromJson(news));
        //print(news["title"]);
      }
      return objects;
    }
    throw Exception('Failed to fetch near earth objects');
  }
  final ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _scrollController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black87,
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.indigo.shade900,
        title: const Text("......"),
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder<List<News>>(
        future: newsFuture,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return Center(
              child: LoadingAnimationWidget.newtonCradle(
                  color: const Color.fromRGBO(98, 2, 255, 1.0), size: 100),
            );
          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Center(child: Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}'));
          } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
            final newsList = snapshot.data!;
            return ListView.separated(
              physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
              controller: _scrollController,
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: newsList.length,
              separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return const SizedBox(
                    height: 32.0); // Adjust the height as desired
              },
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                final object = newsList[index];
                return NewsContainer(
                  title: object.title,
                  description: object.description,
                  imageUrl: object.urlToImage,
                  onButtonPressed: (){
                    _launchInWebViewOrVC(Uri.parse(object.url));
                  },
                  onDoubleTap: (){
                    _launchInWebViewOrVC(Uri.parse(object.urlToImage));
                  },
                );
              },
            );
          } else {
            return Container();
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class News {
  final String title;
  final String source;
  final String description;
  final String url;
  final String urlToImage;
  final String content;

  News(
      {required this.title,
        required this.source,
        required this.url,
        required this.content,
        required this.description,
        required this.urlToImage});

  factory News.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return News(
      title: json['title'] ?? '',
      source: json["source"]?["name"] ?? '',
      description: json["description"] ?? '',
      url: json["url"] ?? '',
      content: json["content"] ?? '',
      urlToImage: json["urlToImage"] ?? '',
    );
  }
}
```